# Input Validation for character array in c++

Tags: c++, validation

I want input validation in my C++ program. I need only characters and numbers in my input otherwise program must return false status. e.g
Valid Data:    "Anthony25isValid"         Invalid Data: "Anthon-25 not Valid"

I wrote the following program but am not getting the desired result.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isValidData( char data[60] );
int main()
{
    char data[60];
    cin.get(data,60);
    bool name = isValidData(data);
    cout<<name;
}
bool isValidData( char data[60] ) {

    if ( data[59] != '\0' )
        return false;
    int i=0;
    while(data[i]!='\0') {
        if ( !isalpha(data[i])  || !isdigit(data[i])){
            return false;
        }
        i++;    
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `data[59] != '\0'` has undefined behaviour unless you've read exactly 60 characters with `cin.get`. Initialisation is cheap: `char data[60] = {};`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in this line.

```
if ( !isalpha(data[i])  || !isdigit(data[i])){
    return false;
}
```

You want to return false if the char is not alpha AND not digit.
The following should work

```
if ( !isalpha(data[i])  && !isdigit(data[i])){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked and what if I need 60 or less characters? I coded this 
if ( data[59] != '\0' )
        return false;
means at index 59 if it is not null character then it must return false. But this is not working rather.

Comment: You are only reading 60 characters currently. You can read the whole to a string and check if the size is <= 60.

Comment: But It's not returning false if I input more than 60 characters though.

Comment: Because you are only reading 60 ^^ You could do something like reading 61 and check if the last one was written.

Answer (score 0):

You're using C++, do it the C++ way

```
  string line;
  getline(std::cin, line)
  bool inputValid = true;
  for(int i = 0; i < line.size() ; i++) //C++11
    if(!(isalpha(line[i])  || isdigit(line[i]) )
        { inputValid = false; break; }
```

You can use `auto` as well, if C++11 is being used, makes code concise.

```
  for(auto iChar : line) //C++11
    if(!(isalpha(iChar)  || isdigit(iChar) )
        { inputValid = false; break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, I suggest you to use `string`. Check this solution below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isValidData(string data);
int main()
{
    char data[60];
    cin.get(data, 60);
    string tmp_data = data;
    bool name = isValidData(tmp_data);
    cout << name;
}
bool isValidData(string data) {
    bool hasOnlyLetterDigit = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if ( !isdigit(data.at(i)) && !isalpha(data.at(i)) ) {
            hasOnlyLetterDigit = false;
        }
    }
    return hasOnlyLetterDigit;
}
```